# How to GROUP BY max date in left join

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have three tables in Oracle DB

```
House (
  id
)

Person (
  id,
  house_id
)

Bill (
  id,
  date,
  amount,
  person_id
)
```

I need to get  list if person id and amount from last bill if exist by house id. Last bill is the bill with the oldest date field.
I can get it by person id this way:

```
SELECT
 p.id,
 b.amount
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT amount FROM Bill WHERE date =
 (SELECT MAX(date) FROM Bill b1 WHERE person_id = 1)
) b ON b.person_id = p.id 
WHERE p.id = 1;
```

Haw can I get list of person ids with amounts of latest bill by house id?

Sample data:

```
House(id:1)
House(id:2)

Person(id:1, house_id:1)
Person(id:2, house_id:1)
Person(id:3, house_id:2)

Bill(id:1, date:01-11-2011, amount:100, person_id:1)
Bill(id:2, date:01-11-2012, amount:200, person_id:1)
Bill(id:3, date:01-11-2011, amount:90, person_id:2)
Bill(id:4, date:01-11-2012, amount:10, person_id:2)
Bill(id:5, date:01-11-2011, amount:190, person_id:3)
```

Result for select by house_id = 1:

```
person_id:1, amount:200
person_id:2, amount:10
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff done

Comment: If you added a record `Person(id:4, house_id:1)` but no related bill, would you want to show the person 4 with an amount of zero or null or would you not show person 4?

Comment: And you don't want to show the date in your results?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner No, just amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation:

```
select p.person_id,
       max(b.amount) keep (dense_rank first order by b.date desc) as most_recent_amount
from bill b join
     person p
     on b.person_id = p.id
where p.house_id = 1
group by p.person_id;
```